# Getting stack overflow on function call

Tags: c++, inheritance, stack-overflow

I have a base class that three classes inherit from. Whenever these child classes are instantiated in a function, I'll get a stack overflow right as the function enters the body. They could be instantiated near the end or the beginning, it doesn't matter. As soon as the function body is entered, I get a stack overflow. If the classes are removed, the function operates normally. The child classes do not contain anything but one overridden function, and their constructors and destructors. The constructors and destructors are all empty.

```
int main()
{
    Borrow borrow;

    MovieStore store( "STORE!!!!!!" );
    store.initalize();
    store.processTransaction();

    return 0;
}
```

Not sure how much that would help, but basically borrow is the child class. Once the function body is entered, a stack overflow results. Even if I instantiated it before return 0, it would still crash on entering the function body. If it is removed, program runs normally. I'm actually declaring borrow in a different function (main is just shorter) but it has the same effects whatever function it is placed into.

```
class Borrow : public Transaction
{
public:
    Borrow();
    virtual ~Borrow();


    virtual void perform( Customer *, Item * );
};
```

Borrow and the other child classes are the same. Empty constructor and destructor with one overridden virtual function.

The implementation of perform is:

```
void Borrow::perform( Customer *customer, Item *aMovie )
{
    customer->addMovie( aMovie, "B" );
}
```

Comment: Please share some code so we can see what you're up against.

Comment: You should show the code, the mistake cannot be seen from your description.

Comment: Some example code showing the behavior would be good.  And even though the question can probably be deduced here (e.g., why does the stack overflow occur?), it is typically good form to actually ask a question.

Comment: The base class doesn't happen to be large in size?

Comment: @UncleBens I don't think it is. It is just the constructor, destructor, and a pure virtual function.

Comment: @ShrimpCrackers Since the error has something to do with the instantiation, show us the constructor of `Borrow` and it's parent class. What you posted now isn't going to help any to answer the question.

Comment: @Mahesh All the child class constructors are empty, including the base class.

Comment: What is the implementation of `perform`?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace, and have you checked it for any repeated patterns? Perhaps you've got a call loop of some kind going on.

Comment: @UncleBens Thank you for asking the question "No data members?" It made me realize that I had a large database object as a member. Removing it solved the problem. Thank you. Post for points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to UncleBens, I was able to figure out that a class with a large object was being instantiated multiple times and thus creating a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your function is recursive and you never stop to call it.

Comment: No recursive functions or methods. There is a while loop that reads from a file that is stopped with eof().